# Recursion to iteration without stack and goto - just a theoretic exercise

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Recently I tried to explain to somebody how "easy" it is to convert A recursion code to iteration. The simple factorial or fibo examples were in fact easy to explain. Then we switch to binary trees and unfortunately I was not able to replace simple recursion code with its simple iteration alternative.

Here is the code to be replaced:

```
public class Test {
public static void bincR2(int i,int k, String buff) {
    if(i<k) {
        bincR2(i+1,k,buff + '0');
        bincR2(i+1,k,buff + '1');
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println(buff);
    }
}    

public static void bincI(int k, String buff) {
// ????
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;
    String b = "";
    bincR2(0,n, b);     
    bincI(n, b);

}   
}
```

The results should be print out of a binary representation of a all numbers from 0 to 2^n-1. For n=3 obviously it is:
000
001
010
011 ... 111

Of course i can generate such a set of strings in a loop with several different ways from simple string formatting to shifting the number and checking the last bit. But I'm looking for a solution as closed as possible to the recursion method. I don't want to use own stack and "goto" statement or any advanced string method,  just loops, conditions and variables - it must be somehow possible as already stated in a few threads here. Java was chosen since there is no goto statement :)

Any idea is very welcome.

Comment: Another example of a tree structure is the directory and file structure in a partition on a hard drive. There's no easy iterative way to visit every file in a partition without some type of stack. Then there's the possible goal of visiting all files within a current directory before visiting any sub-directories (two loops, the first loop iterates through files, the second loop iterates through directories, calling itself (or using a stack) for each directory).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to produce 2^n values. With just loops without recursion you cannot get anything over polynomial complexity (can you? unless you iterate to something that's not polynomial in n, but then you're not mimicking recursive solution, are you?), so I'm afraid you need to compensate with space complexity -- something like below, but that's kinda cheating, since it's still "implementing own stack". I'd be interested to know better solution myself.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int N = 4;

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add("");

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            List <String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String str : result) {
                tmp.add(str + "0");
                tmp.add(str + "1");
            }
            result = tmp;
        }

        for (String str : result) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    }
}
```

**Before commenting on this answer, please make sure you understand the question, which is NOT just about generating all binary strings.**

Comment: > something like below, but that's kinda cheating, since it's still "implementing own stack". Unfortunately True! I'm afraid I was too quick saying to my kid that it is simple to de-recurse a given code. Anyway I'd like the way you solve it.

Comment: @Peter exactly. However, see argument about complexity. interesting question, by the way!

Comment: _However, see argument about complexity. interesting question, by the way!_ - I asked my kid to generate some simple algorithms always both ways - just in terms "train your brain" - and created a trap for myself. After being sitting now for a few hours I have to give up. Now the massage to my kid is - this is the reason some languages make recursion possible - just to enjoy simplicity of the solutions. Anyway thanks for sharing your code and opinion.

Comment: @avsk: > 'but that's kinda cheating, since it's still "implementing own stack".' Nah; you're certainly creating some sort of 'accumulator', but the same can be said for the usual 'Factorial' or 'Fib' type of examples. What you successfully avoid here is an /additional/ penalty of memory usage for the nested stack frames that are generated in the recursive approach; which is usually why one wishes to reformulate from a recursive approach to a non-r one.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this can be done with two loops mimicking the recursion as an expression of frequency: the outer loop from `2^(k-1)` down to `2^0` and the inner loop from `0` to `2^k - 1`. Keep a counter variable, corresponding with the outer loop, that will mark cycle length. Each time a cycle completes, switch from appending "0"s to appending "1"s.

For example, `k = 3, Array length = 2^3 = 8, Cycles = 2^2, 2^1, 2^0`:

```
First append: switch from 0s to 1s every 4th
0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1

Second append: switch from 0s to 1s every 2nd
00  00  01  01  10  10  11  11

Third append: switch from 0s to 1s every iteration
000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

Comment: could you please provide a working code snippet for you idea? I'm afraid you algorithm will work only with a fixed k - you somehow hardcoded 3 loops for k=3. Increasing k, needs another loop.

Comment: @Peter This seems to be nice approach. You can start with pre-build array of empty strings of length 2^k. Then you have a loop from k-1 to 0, inside it you loop from 0 to 2^k-1, going through array and flipping the bits as described, with the step determined by the outer loop. Two nested loops, k full passes through array. However, if I'm not mistaken, the complexity here is O(k2^k), and mine or recursive solution is O(2^k), so it's not straightforward translation of recursion.

Comment: @avysk thank you for reading and commenting. Think more carefully about your complexity analysis: how could the total number of character-accessing operations of any computer program be any less than `k * 2^k` when that is the minimum number of output characters?

Comment: Of course I consider all string operations to be atomic (like "whatever string" + "1" be O(1)). It won't be such in real life, but I can append 0/1s from the start of the string, not to the end, and in some languages such operation will be O(1) (new string is just a list, reusing old list as a tail, without re-allocations). Then "" -> {"0", "1"} -> {"00", "10", "01", "11"} takes 6 operations to generate 8 characters of output. (We exclude *printing* of the output here, of course.)

Comment: And if we consider appending to a string be non-atomic but O(length), your solution is O(k^2 * 2^k), I think.

Comment: @avysk I don't see how a computer can generate 8 characters in 6 character-type operations. (By the way, my idea can be modified to apply each append as direct-access rather than technically passing through previous string characters to get to its end. For one thing, it can be prepend rather than append.)

Comment: I just described above how. The tails of the strings are re-used. Imagine the following memory layout (-> means "points to"). a -> x, b -> x, c -> y, d -> y, x -> z, y -> z. You have 6 elements in memory (a, b, c, x, y, z) but they describe 4 strings of length 3: "axz", "bxz", "cyz", "dyz", for total size of 12. Re non-appending: you're right, you can do bit-flipping in O(1) instead of appending.

Comment: @avysk you seem to have efficiently described a "route" for producing 12 characters. But walking that route takes at least 12 steps no matter what.

Comment: Nope, I have now 4 entities in my program with total size of 12: string a, string b, string c and string d. **Outputting** them indeed will take O(k2^k), but I've already mentioned that above.

Comment: Actually, we are simply talking about the same thing from different points of view. From the point of view of Thuring model of computation you are completely right; I was talking here rather about purely functional data structures (and, if we look at Java, your approach is closer to reality).

Comment: @avysk that's a good point about efficiently holding the structure in memory.